# Handling Non-SSL Traffic in Python/Tornado

Tags: python, ssl, tornado

I have a webservice running in python 2.7.10 / Tornado that uses SSL.  This service throws an error when a non-SSL call comes through (http://...).

I don't want my service to be accessible when SSL is not used, but I'd like to handle it in a cleaner fashion.

Here is my main code that works great over SSL:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    #does not work on 2.7.6
    ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
    ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain("...crt.pem","...key.pem")
    ssl_ctx.load_verify_locations("...CA.crt.pem")
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application, ssl_options=ssl_ctx, decompress_request=True)
    http_server.listen(options.port)

    mainloop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

    print("Main Server started on port XXXX")
    mainloop.start()
```

and here is the error when I hit that server with http://... instead of https://...:

```
[E 151027 20:45:57 http1connection:700] Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 691, in _server_request_loop
    ret = yield conn.read_response(request_delegate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 807, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 209, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 810, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 166, in _read_message
    quiet_exceptions=iostream.StreamClosedError)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 807, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 209, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
SSLError: [SSL: HTTP_REQUEST] http request (_ssl.c:590)
```

Any ideas how I should handle that exception?

And what the standard-conform return value would be when I catch a non-SSL call to an SSL-only API?

**UPDATE**

This API runs on a specific port e.g. **https**://example.com:1234/.  I want to inform a user who is trying to connect without SSL, e.g. **http**://example.com:1234/ that what they are doing is incorrect by returning an error message or status code.  As it is the uncaught exception returns a 500, which they could interpret as a programming error on my part.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an [excelent discussion in this Tornado issue](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/523) about that, where [Tornado maintainer](https://github.com/bdarnell) says:

> If you have both HTTP and HTTPS in the same tornado process, you must be running two separate HTTPServers (of course such a feature should not be tied to whether SSL is handled at the tornado level, since you could be terminating SSL in a proxy, but since your question stipulated that SSL was enabled in tornado let's focus on this case first). You could simply give the HTTP server a different Application, one that just does this redirect.

So, the best solution it's to HTTPServer that listens on port 80 and doesn't has the `ssl_options` parameter setted.

**UPDATE**

A request to **https**://example.com/some/path will go to port 443, where you must have an HTTPServer configured to handle https traffic; while a request to **http**://example.com/some/path will go to port 80, where you must have another instance of HTTPServer without ssl options, and this is where you must return the custom response code you want. That shouldn't raise any error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems that the suggestion there is to use a different server on a different port and redirect to the SSL port.  

That doesn't really solve my problem because I want to return an appropriate code when a non-SLL connection is attempted on the SSL port, instead of the 500 that is returned for the uncaught exception.  Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear when I copied & pasted form tornado docs (they are suggesting to make a redirect but I'm not). I've edited my answer to explain it better.

Comment: OK I see, thanks for the clarification.  In this scenario I want to handle the exception that occurs when a user attempts to connect to **http**://example.com:443/some/path . It's a different scenario since my application is an API on a specific port and not a webpage.  I want the user to know they are using the API incorrectly, and not think my server is crashing due to an error on my part.